# Setting up dependencies for PyPi Elevation module?

Tags: python-3, library

I am trying to set up pypi's [elevation module](https://pypi.org/project/elevation/#description) in Miniconda (Python 3.7.3), but I get the following error when I run the selfcheck:

```
(base) C:\Users\name>eio selfcheck
'GNU Make' not found or not usable.
'unzip' not found or not usable.
'gunzip' not found or not usable.
'gdal_translate' not found or not usable.
'gdalbuildvrt' not found or not usable.
```

There is not much guidance on installing the dependencies on the website for someone new, and a couple hours of Google searching and trial-and-errors have not gotten me any closer.

I know this question was asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076943/install-dependencies-for-module-elevation#comment101690725_51076943) a while ago, but the answer is not very good, and perhaps this question is better targeted on this GIS Stack Exchange anyhow.

I don't know how to install the other libraries. `pip install gdal_translate` doesn't work (nor does it work for the other libraries), and I don't know where to begin with the GNU Make issue.

In case it matters, below is a screenshot of the libraries installed (gdal is on there).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using miniconda, use conda to install, not pip unless you have to.

From https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/elevation:

```
conda install -c conda-forge elevation gdal make
```

And since you're using conda, you shouldn't install stuff in the base environment, create a new environment instead:

```
conda create -n elev -c conda-forge elevation gdal make
activate elev
```

The `gdal` package will install the `gdal_translate` and `gdalbuildvrt` commandline tools.

You'll need to find and install (on your PATH) manually [gunzip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net//packages/gzip.htm)/[unzip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net//packages/unzip.htm), as they are not available for Windows via conda.